# Typescript decorators + Reflect metadata

Tags: typescript, reflect-metadata

I'm using a property decorator `Field` which pushes its' key to a `fields` Reflect metadata property:

```js
export function Field(): PropertyDecorator {
    return (target, key) => {
        const fields = Reflect.getMetadata('fields', target) || [];
        if (!fields.includes(key)) {
            fields.push(key)
        }
        Reflect.defineMetadata('fields', fields, target)
    }
}
```

I then have an abstract base-class `Form` that accesses the metadata in a getter accessory:

```js
abstract class Form {
    get fields() {
        return Reflect.getMetadata('fields', this) || [];
    }
}
```

I have so far been able to use it successfully to distinguish form fields from other class properties. Consider these classes:

```js
abstract class UserForm extends Form {
    @Field()
    public firstName: string

    @Field()
    public lastName: string

    get fullName() {
        return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
    }
}

class AdminForm extends UserForm {
    @Field()
    roles: string[]
}

const form = new AdminForm()
console.log(form.fields)
// ['roles', 'firstName', 'lastName']
```

The problem occurs when I define a sister class to `AdminForm` - `MemberForm`. When multiple subclasses exists to `Form` it seems the `fields` getter returns all fields:

```js
class MemberForm extends UserForm {
    @Field()
    memberSince: Date;
}

const form = new AdminForm()
console.log(form.fields)
// ['roles', 'firstName', 'lastName', 'memberSince'] <--!!!
```

This makes no sense to me. Why does the `memberSince` field appear on an instance of `AdminForm`? How can I define different fields on different subclasses?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The problem is `getMetadata` goes down the prototype chain and will always return what is defined on the base type (since that gets assigned first). You need to use `getOwnMetadata` to get the array field of the current class only when you add a new field and when getting the fields you need to walk up the property chain to get all base class fields.

This should work:

```
import 'reflect-metadata'
export function Field(): PropertyDecorator {
  return (target, key) => {
      const fields = Reflect.getOwnMetadata('fields', target) || [];
      if (!fields.includes(key)) {
          fields.push(key)
      }
      Reflect.defineMetadata('fields', fields, target)
  }
}

abstract class Form {
  get fields() {
      let fields = []
      let target = Object.getPrototypeOf(this);
      while(target != Object.prototype) {
        let childFields = Reflect.getOwnMetadata('fields', target) || [];
        fields.push(...childFields);
        target = Object.getPrototypeOf(target);
      }
      return fields;
  }
}

abstract class UserForm extends Form {
  @Field()
  public firstName!: string

  @Field()
  public lastName!: string

  get fullName() {
      return this.firstName + ' ' + this.lastName;
  }
}

class AdminForm extends UserForm {
  @Field()
  roles!: string[]
}

const form1 = new AdminForm()
console.log(form1.fields) // ['roles', 'firstName', 'lastName']

class MemberForm extends UserForm {
  @Field()
  memberSince!: Date;
}

const form2 = new MemberForm()
console.log(form2.fields) // ["memberSince", "firstName", "lastName"]
```

Comment: Interesting! If I change `getMetadata` to `getOwnMetadata` on the property decorator, then I get `['roles']` on `fields`. So what do you mean by walking up the property chain?

Comment: Wow! That's amazing! Thanks a lot!