# How parent class get all children properties data using decorator in typescript?

Tags: typescript, metadata, abstract-class, typescript-decorator, pass-data

My purpose: Children class can use function of Parent abstract class without pass any explicit data to the parent. And decorator can get the value of children properties class.

Code example:

```
abstract class Parent{
constructor(){}
calc(){
a = children property 1;
b = children property 2;
console.log("result: " + a*b);
}
}

class Children extends Parent{

@propertydecorator
a : number;
@propertydecorator
b : number;
constructor(no1:number, no2: number){
this.a = no1;
this.b = no2;
}
}
```

To use this Children class:

```
const children = new Children(2, 4);
children.calc() //function extends from Parent
```

and result should was:

```
result: 8
```

Ask: How can i do above task with decorator? Or any thing else help me complete my purpose?
Thank in advance!

Comment: You made a typo on the word `constructor`. Try to change `contructor` to `constructor`.

Comment: Is this correct? If it's correct i will write the answer. https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/IYIwzgLgTsDGEAJYBthjAgCsKBTAdogN4BQCCwAXAvgK4C2IuUCAvAgAwDcZCI1dRszace5WAHt8kKLXgSoACio0GTKABo+AtcwCUCUuXIQAFgEswAOmAjgY42ctWQIkA4C+vWMGSxFBkbGktISyLhWyBIA5ooARHhgtMgQ1HEIANQITta2AFTZFtYgep4kXiQoaBgAwhbIACZ4+Ai4AB4QBA0Y2M3E3lIychAKyjpCmtqqE4G85EkADszKWiVlFSGQSPVNBCL4uADuCHXmjc2KAExaACyllTvNVj5+ASRAA.

Comment: It's ```constructor```

Comment: @kennarddh it's a way to do these task. It's correct but I prefer using other ways such as decorator and metadata, and of course I am still finding the answer

Comment: Hmm is that the requirement? But in typescript you must call super in child class. Probably you must write custom transpiler for that decorator usage.

Comment: I found out the way to address this issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55117125/typescript-decorators-reflect-metadata

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Typescript decorators + Reflect metadata](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55117125/typescript-decorators-reflect-metadata)